# How to set title in each table TD from TD text ( legacy datatable ) using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatable, legacy

So the question would be, in a legacy jquery datatable ( not the "new" version of it ) how can i set a title on the cell(td) with its content?

Comment: SO supports self-answered questions. Please edit your answer in the form of a question, one that does not presuppose an answer. Then answer your question in separate "answer" post.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

And here is the code:

In the properties of the datatable(**$("#MySpecialDatatable").datatable({properties})**):

```
...
"fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {                 
                $("#MySpecialDatatable tbody tr").each(function () {
                    var nTds = $('td', this);
                    $(nTds).each(function () {
                        var td = this;
                        td.setAttribute('title', $(td).text());
                    });
                });
            },
    ...
```